# Is it a good practice to wrap native HTML elements within a div element when creating custom components?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-redux

Ok, let say I want to create my custom react "native" elements (`<a>`,`<h1>`, ...) with some custom styles.

Which one of these `<A>` elements is the best practice to choose?

```
/*
 *
 *`<A>` unwrapped
 *
 */ 

import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles.scss';

const A = () => {
  render() {
    const { className, children, ...attrs } = this.props;
    const classes = className ? [styles.base, className] : [styles.base];

    return (
      <a 
        className={classes.join(' ')}
        {...attrs}>
        {children}
      </a>
    );
  }
}

A.propTypes = {
  className: React.PropTypes.string,
  children: React.PropTypes.any,
};

export default A;
```

OR

```
/*
 *
 *`<A>` wrapped by a div
 *
 */ 

import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles.scss';

const A = () => {
  render() {
    const { className, children, ...attrs } = this.props;
    const classes = className ? [styles.base, className] : [styles.base];

    return (
      <div className={classes.join(' ')}>
        <a {...attrs}>
          {children}
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

A.propTypes = {
  className: React.PropTypes.string,
  children: React.PropTypes.any,
};

export default A;
```

Considering:

- Developer perspective
- CSS selectors perspective
- HTML perspective

Comment: Opinion based, but I'd go without wrapping in an extra `<div />`, especially for inline-level elements to avoid restyling the div as inline when you need a link in a paragraph of text.

Comment: 1 more div > 1 more depth level on the DOM for EACH component. Sounds too much to me, I'd go with first solution too